# BackboneJS Magnific Popup URL's

Tags: backbone.js, magnific-popup

Is there a way to display a thumbnail of a youtube video in a BackboneJS view, then after clicking the thumbnail a lightbox opens and plays the video and at the same time the URL changes, so that you actually can send the URL-link?

I have a Backbone App where I list multiple Artists and when you click on one of those you get to an artist specific page where the user among other things can watch videos. So lets say you are on Lady Gaga's page and i click on a video, the `Magnific Popup`-opens with the video. But what I want to achieve i that the URL changes as well. something like ladygaga/videos/titleofvideo(or youtubelink):

Right now, in my Backbone View I have:

```
events: {
    'click .video' : 'popUp'
},

popUp: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video').magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: false
    });
}
```

The popup works fine, I just need the URL to change... Does anyone have an idea how to add this here if it is possible?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is less concerning backbone and more to do with a lightbox plugin and the Youtube API.

Comment: Please try to narrow the problem. Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: @Lix I just edited my question... hope you get the idea

Comment: This is a classic case for using a hash in the URL ( like ladygaga#video/title ). When you open the popup, use javascript to change the URL, and when the page is loaded and the hash is set, open the popup automatically.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer ah ok, I updated my question a bit, not sure if I can use your suggestion here...